# Gave up waiting for service error: during pax exam integration tests in opendaylight

Tags: maven, opendaylight, pax-exam, integration-testing

I'm developing an app on Opendaylight using the startup archetype. I'm using the Carbon version and after running mvn install, I get this error during the pax exam integration tests:

org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.tracker.ServiceLookupException: gave up waiting for service org.opendaylight.controller.sal.binding.api.BindingAwareBroker

Can anyone help me with this error please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That message just means that the MD SAL data store is not up and running. You need to look into the Karaf logs from the IT to understand why that is so - look around in the `*Test-output.txt`, `*Test.txt` and `*Test.xml` files in `target/surefire-reports/` of your failing integration test artifact.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I tried running mvn clean install and the build was succeed. I didn't change anything so for now hope it will stay like that. If compiling again I get the same error, I will post the logs because at the time of error I checked these logs and couldn't figure out what was wrong. Thanks once again!